# Can I "decipher" a puzzle?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, phrase-request

> Since elementary school, I loved **deciphering** puzzles, logical and otherwise.

Would this word choice be correct? What are synonyms you might use for solve?

Comment: You could say "decipher a puzzle" if it were encrypted (or *enciphered*) but otherwise it would be the wrong word. Remember what Mark Twain said: "The difference between the right word and *almost* the right word is the difference between lightning and a lightning bug."

Comment: You are encouraged to [wait longer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer. You are more likely to receive more answers that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Decipher*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decipher) is usually used when talking about a code or secret message, or when talking about trying to understand the meaning of something abstract or confusing (or than a puzzle).

If you are talking about a puzzle that uses cryptic language or codes, it is possible to say "I deciphered the message" or "I deciphered the code". However, we usually ***solve*** puzzles.

> [puzzle](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/puzzle)
>   1. a toy, problem, or other contrivance designed to amuse by presenting difficulties to be **solved** by ingenuity or patient effort.

The following are some search results. Notice that "decipher a/the puzzle" does not map, just for comparison.

[image]

When talking about some puzzles, like jigsaw or crossword puzzles, you could say "I finished the puzzle."

When talking about some puzzles, like ones dealing with some kind of secret message, you could say "I [figured out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/figure%20out) the puzzle."

You could also say, "I loved [working on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+on) puzzles."